# Determining the center of the p-Sylow subgroup of $S_p $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

My Algebra book says without proof that the center of the p-Sylow subgroup (we will call it P) of $S_p$ is the subgroup itself.

Now I can understand that P will be a subset of its center as it is of prime order, and hence cyclic. However, I can't understand why no other element outside of P can be part of its center. Any help understanding this would be great.

Comment: You are confusing center with centralizer. The center $Z(P)$ is a subset of $P$ by definition. The centralizer $C_{S_p}(P)$ however is in fact strictly bigger than $P$, because there are elements outside of $P$ that commute with every element of $P$.

Comment: Also BTW there is more than one $p$-Sylow subgroup of $S_p$.

Comment: Basically, all that is being said here is that a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $S_p$ is abelian. Note that $p$ is the highest power of $p$ dividing $p!$, so yes, any Sylow $p$-subgroup is cyclic. In general, however, this subgroup is not unique.

Answer (score 3):

Like anon I assume that the question is about the centralizer of $P$ (with that typo/mistranslation the question makes IMHO more sense).

The highest power of $p$ that divides $p!$ is $p^1$. Therefore the Sylow subgroups $P$ are all cyclic of order $p$. A permutation of prime order $p$ must be a product of disjoint $p$-cycles (ignoring fixed points). In the case of $S_p$ there is room for only one disjoint $p$-cycle, so we know that $P$ is generated by a $p$-cycle, call it $\sigma$. Because $P=\langle\sigma\rangle$ the centralizer of $P$ equals the centralizer of $\sigma$, $C_{S_p}(\sigma)$.

Let's take a detour via conjugacy classes. We know from basic properties of symmetric groups that the conjugates of $\sigma$ are exactly all the $p$-cycles in $S_p$. How many are there? A $p$-cycle in $S_p$ will move all the numbers $1,2,3,\ldots,p$. Recall that in cycle notation we can choose the starting point of the cycle any way we want without changing the cycle, but no other changes are possible. So we can write all $p$-cycles $\alpha$ of $S_p$ uniquely in such a way that they begin with a $1$. We then have $p-1$ choices for the next number $=\alpha(1)$, $p-2$ choices for the next $=\alpha(\alpha(1))$ et cetera. Therefore there are exactly $(p-1)!$ different $p$-cycles in $S_p$. In other words, the conjugacy class $[\sigma]$ of $\sigma$ has size $(p-1)!$.

But [the orbit-stabilizer theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Orbit-stabilizer_theorem_and_Burnside.27s_lemma) (often 
introduced at about the same time as [the class equation](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Class_equation_of_a_group)) tells us that
$$
(p-1)!=|[\sigma]|=\frac{|S_p|}{|C_{S_p}(\sigma)|}=\frac{p!}{|C_{S_p}(\sigma)|}.
$$
This implies that the centralizer $C_{S_p}(\sigma)$ has order $p$. Clearly $P\subseteq C_{S_p}(\sigma)$, so this means that we must have equality
$$
P=\langle\sigma\rangle=C_{S_p}(\sigma)=C_{S_p}(P).
$$

Comment: Observe that it is crucial here that we are working inside $S_p$. If the symmetric group is $S_n$, $n>p+1$, then the centralizer can be strictly larger (this fits, and is one of the reasons why I think the question really is about centralizers). For example in $S_9$ the 2-cycle $(89)$ clearly commutes with the $7$-cycle $\sigma=(1234567)$, so the centralizer will have an even order. The exact order of the centralizer of a Sylow $p$-subgroup can be calculated along the lines of my answer when $n<2p$ (the bound coming from the fact that after that point Sylow subgroup is no longer cyclic).

Comment: It looks like the exact order of the centralizer of a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $S_n$ is $(n\,\mathrm{mod}\,p)!$.

Comment: @QuangHoang: We get a factor of that form, but the centralizer is bigger. The center of $P$ is surely contained in the centralizer, and a $p$-group always has a non-trivial center. For example in $S_{2p}$, a Sylow $p$-subgroup is abelian, isomorphic to $C_p\times C_p$. Similarly up to $S_{p(p-1)}$. With $S_{p^2}$ it gets more complicated, I haven't checked, but I think the center of that Sylow $p$-subgroup has order $p$ only. A Sylow $p$ of $S_{p^2+p}$ is a direct product of those of $S_{p^2}$ and $S_p$ et cetera.

Comment: I did miss that center of $p$-group part. And I think the next part is correct, we only get a $C_p$ component for each power of $p$: The center of $G\wr C_p\cong G^p\rtimes C_p$ is the diagonal of $Z(G)^p$.